# Running a 5V, 4pin pwm fan with Mega2560

Tags: power, display, atmega2560

I have a Mega2560 and would like to use it to power a single fan and display. The fan is a 5V fan that draws 260mA and I can't find power specs for this display. I can't find a clear answer for how much current I can safely draw off of the 5V pins on this board. Does anyone know if I'll be able to run these devices off of my Mega2560?

Board: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B01H4ZLZLQ

Display: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B085NHM5TC/

Fan: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07DXR1Y73/

Comment: yes, the manufacturer knows ... read their datasheet

Comment: Your board has an AMS1117 voltage regulator, google the part number for its datasheet. For display, even you can't find the data, you can measure it easily by turning on all the display segments.

Comment: Your board has an AMS1117 voltage regulator, google the part number for its datasheet. For display, even you can't find the data, you can measure it easily by turning on all the display segments.